# Recursive bubble sort in OCaml

Tags: sorting, ocaml

I'm new in OCaml and just want to be sure that I write code in "ocaml way". My other first programs in OCaml was imperative and looks like python-code. So I decided to write simple code and share it for review.

```
let print lst =
    List.map string_of_int lst
        |> String.concat " "
        |> print_endline
;;


let rec sort lst =
    let sorted = match lst with
    | hd1 :: hd2 :: tl ->
        if hd1 > hd2 then
            hd2 :: sort (hd1 :: tl)
        else
            hd1 :: sort (hd2 :: tl)
    | tl -> tl
    in
    if lst = sorted then
        lst
    else
        sort sorted
;;


let () =
    let lst1 = [3; 4; 2; 1] in
    print lst1;
    sort lst1 |> print;

    let lst2 = [5; 6; 7; 0; 1; 4; 2; 9; 3; 8] in
    print lst2;
    sort lst2 |> print;
;;
```

Result:

```
3 4 2 1
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 0 1 4 2 9 3 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is easy to understand, so I can only suggest minor changes. The first thing is just a preference of mine: if a function body is nothing but a `match ... with` expression, I use the `function` keyword, instead. The second, more important recommendation is to use three clauses in the match body so you don't build a new, temporary list (`hd2 :: tl`) as you recurse. With both of these minor changes, `sort` looks like this:

```
let rec sort lst =
  let sorted = function
  | hd1 :: hd2 :: tl when hd1 > hd2 ->
        hd2 :: sort (hd1 :: tl)
  | hd1 :: tl ->
        hd1 :: sort tl
  | tl -> tl
in
if lst = sorted then
    lst
else
    sort sorted
```

As the list gets more and more sorted, the second pattern gets matched more often and simply travels down the list. Your version continues to build a new list -- even when the list is sorted.

One other thing: OCaml has an equality operator that tests for physical equality (in addition to structural equality.) So we can avoid building a new list in the second case, if it's not necessary:

```
| (hd1 :: tl) as lst ->
    let tl' = sort tl in
    if tl' == tl then
        lst
    else
        hd1 :: tl'
```

Both these changes will prevent a lot of temporary objects from being created. Unfortunately, it's still a bubble sort, so it's never going to be a speed-demon. :D